# NestJS/TypeORM - connecting to multiple databases - ConnectionNotFoundError

Tags: nestjs, typeorm

Connecting to **two databases** using TypeORM and NestJS throws a **ConnectionNotFoundError** when a custom repository is registered using the connection **(UserConnection & PhotoConnection)** one for each database. I have created a minimal repo here https://github.com/masonridge/connissuewithndb. The TypeOrm registration is done in the AppModule of NestJS

**(app.module.ts)**

```
@Module({
  imports: [

    TypeOrmModule.forRootAsync({
      name: 'PhotoConnection',
      useFactory: async () => {
        return {
          type: 'sqlite',
          synchronize: true,
          database: 'TestPhoto.sqlite',
          entities: [Photo],
        } as SqliteConnectionOptions;
      },
    }),
    TypeOrmModule.forRootAsync({
      name: 'UserConnection',
      useFactory: async () => {
        return {
          type: 'sqlite',
          synchronize: true,
          database: 'TestUser.sqlite',
          entities: [User],
        } as SqliteConnectionOptions;
      },
    }),
    // TypeOrmModule.forFeature([User, UserRepository], 'UserConnection'),
    // TypeOrmModule.forFeature([Photo, PhotoRepository], 'PhotoConnection'),
    PhotoModule, UserModule,
  ],
```

**(photo.module.ts) DB connection1 - PhotoConnection is registered here**

```
@Module({
  imports: [    
    TypeOrmModule.forFeature([PhotoRepository], 'PhotoConnection'),
  ],
  providers: [
    PhotoService,
  ],
  controllers: [PhotoController],
  exports: [TypeOrmModule],
})
export class PhotoModule {}
```

**(user.module.ts) DB connection2 - UserConnection is registered here**

```
@Module({
  imports: [
    TypeOrmModule.forFeature([UserRepository], 'UserConnection'),
  ],
  providers: [
    UserService,
  ],
  exports: [TypeOrmModule],
  controllers: [UserController],
})
export class UserModule {}
```

**(user.repository.ts) Custom repository**

```
@EntityRepository(User)
export class UserRepository extends Repository<User> {
  async createUser(name: string): Promise<string> {
    const user = this.create();
    user.username = name;
    user.salt = 'salt';
    user.password = 'xxkdkdk';
    user.save();
    return name;
  }
}
```

**(photo.repository.ts)**

```
@EntityRepository(Photo)
export class PhotoRepository extends Repository<Photo> {
  async createPhoto(name: string): Promise<string> {
    const photo = this.create();
    photo.name = name;
    photo.save();
    return name;
  }
}
```

The repo is injected into the service using the connection (PhotoConnection)
**(photo.service.ts)**

```
export class PhotoService {
  constructor(
    @InjectRepository(Photo, 'PhotoConnection')
        private readonly photoRepository: PhotoRepository,
  ) {}
```

and here using **UserConnection (user.service.ts)**

```
@Injectable()
export class UserService {
  constructor(
    @InjectRepository(User, 'UserConnection')
    private readonly userRepository: UserRepository,
  ) {}
```

The application starts fine but on a POST request it throws a ConnectionNotFoundError error

> (node:190812) UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: ConnectionNotFoundError: Connection "default" was not found.
>       at new ConnectionNotFoundError (C:\nestjs\type-orm-dbscratch\node_modules\typeorm\error\ConnectionNotFoundError.js:10:28)
>       at ConnectionManager.get (C:\nestjs\type-orm-dbscratch\node_modules\typeorm\connection\ConnectionManager.js:38:19)
>       at Object.getConnection (C:\nestjs\type-orm-dbscratch\node_modules\typeorm\index.js:244:35)
>       at Function.BaseEntity.getRepository (C:\nestjs\type-orm-dbscratch\node_modules\typeorm\repository\BaseEntity.js:67:57)
>       at Photo.BaseEntity.save (C:\nestjs\type-orm-dbscratch\node_modules\typeorm\repository\BaseEntity.js:27:33)
>       at PhotoRepository.createPhoto (C:\nestjs\type-orm-dbscratch\dist\db\photo\photo.repository.js:15:15)
>       at PhotoService.createPhoto (C:\nestjs\type-orm-dbscratch\dist\db\photo\photo.service.js:24:43)
>       at PhotoController.addSetting (C:\nestjs\type-orm-dbscratch\dist\db\photo\photo.controller.js:22:27)
>       at C:\nestjs\type-orm-dbscratch\node_modules@nestjs\core\router\router-execution-context.js:37:29
>       at process._tickCallback (internal/process/next_tick.js:68:7)

I would like to know if there is an issue with the registration. Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It looks like the issue is between using the TypeORM approach of [DataMapper](https://typeorm.io/#/active-record-data-mapper/what-is-the-data-mapper-pattern) and [ActiveRecord](https://typeorm.io/#/active-record-data-mapper/what-is-the-active-record-pattern). It seems using the `ActiveRecord` approach does not support named repositories with NestJS, and as such was looking for connection named `'default'`. If you remove the `extends BaseEntity` and use the repository's save method instead `this.save(user)` vs `user.save()` you'll get a successful save. I didn't see an immediate way to set the connection of the `ActiveRecord` but it may be an option somewhere if that is still the approach you would like to follow.